# How Return Payload to Caller Flow With ActiveMQ in Mule?

Tags: java, jms, mule, activemq-classic

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="jms-connector"  brokerURL="${BrokerURL}" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true"  maxRedelivery="10" durable="true" specification="1.1"/>
<jms:endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector"  name="SyncRequestsQueue" queue="SyncRequestsQueue">
    <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
</jms:endpoint>

<flow name = "RequestsEntryFlow" >
    <http:listener allowedMethods="POST"  parseRequest="false"  config-ref="HTTP_Request_Listener" path="/{name}" doc:name="HTTP Entry Flow" />
    <flow-ref name="requestBeanCreate" />
    <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="request-response" ref="SyncRequestsQueue" /> 
</flow>

<flow name = "SyncRequestsQueueConsumer">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint  connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="request-response" ref="SyncRequestsQueue" />
    <set-variable variableName="id" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-variable variableName="destination" value="#[app.registry.routerBean.getDestination(app.registry.messageBean.getReceiverID(payload))]"  doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-payload value="#[app.registry.messageBean.sendRequestToDestination(payload)]" />
    <processor-chain>
        <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://#[flowVars.destination]" exchange-pattern="request-response">
             <transformer ref="contentTypeTextXML"/>
        </http:outbound-endpoint>                     
        <expression-component>
            app.registry.messageBean.sendResponseToSender(flowVars.id);
            app.registry.messageBean.messageProcessedSuccessfully(flowVars.id);
        </expression-component>
    </processor-chain>
</flow>
```

This is the scenario:

A requests to a remote service comes in to RequestsEntryFlow. 
I do some logging stuff with it and send it to SyncRequestsQueue. 
The SyncRequestsQueueConsumer consumes the queue and sends the content to a remote server.
Now i want to return the response of remote server back to RequestsEntryFlow and from there back to the service Caller.
but the response is not getting back to service caller.

note: when i eliminate JMS and Activemq from the code and use SyncRequestsQueueConsumer as a sub-flow everything works fine. so i guess JMS connectors are not working the way i need them.

What is wrong with the code and how can i solve it? thank you

**--EDIT--**

I have changed my code to adopt  scope and now it looks like this :

```
<flow name = "RequestsEntryFlow" >
    <http:listener allowedMethods="POST"  parseRequest="false"  config-ref="HTTP_Request_Listener" path="/{name}" doc:name="HTTP Entry Flow" />
    <flow-ref name="requestBeanCreate" />                          

    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[app.registry.messageBean.isEMCRequired(payload)]">
            <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector"  ref="EMCRequiredRequestsQueue" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>                         
         <request-reply>
                <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="one-way" ref="SyncRequestsQueue" />
                <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="one-way"  queue="ResponseTempQueue" >
                    <set-payload value="#[payload.get(0)]"/>
                    <remove-property propertyName="Content_Type"/>
                    <transformer ref="contentTypeTextXML"/>
                </jms:inbound-endpoint>
             </request-reply>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>        
</flow>

<flow name = "SyncRequestsQueueConsumer">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="request-response" ref="SyncRequestsQueue" />
    <set-variable variableName="id" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-variable variableName="destination" value="#[app.registry.routerBean.getDestination(app.registry.messageBean.getReceiverID(payload))]"  doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-payload value="#[app.registry.messageBean.sendRequestToDestination(payload)]" />

    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://#[flowVars.destination]" exchange-pattern="request-response">
    <transformer ref="contentTypeTextXML"/>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>                          
    <expression-component>
        app.registry.messageBean.sendResponseToSender(flowVars.id);
        app.registry.messageBean.messageProcessedSuccessfully(flowVars.id);
    </expression-component>

</flow>
```

If i add e logger to my code it will print the proper payload (the response from server)

```
                <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="one-way"  queue="ResponseTempQueue" >
                    <set-payload value="#[payload.get(0)]"/>
                    <remove-property propertyName="Content_Type"/>
                    <transformer ref="contentTypeTextXML"/>
                    <logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" />
                </jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

but the response is not routing back to sender through HTTP

Answer (score 1):

try with request-reply scope in RequestsEntryFlow

in request reply scope in the request block define your SyncRequestsQueue and a VM in reply block of request-reply scope.

in SyncRequestsQueueConsumer flow at the end of flow define the VM with same queue name as defined in reply block of request-reply scope.

Comment: can you show some code sample? cant follow what you replied

Comment: by the way everything in RequestsEntryFlow is request-response

Comment: even though it was mentioned request-response on jms outbound the response will be acknowledgement from jms not the payload

Comment: I think that is not entirely true. When you specify the request-response behaviour in the jms outbound endpoint, it will create a temporary queue and set the replyTo property with that. The inbound jms endpoint will then respond to that temp queue with the payload.

Comment: i have adopted request reply scope but the payload is not getting back to sender through http

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are not using the request-reply correctly. Can you please go through sample implementation of request-reply scope and understand the request-reply scope.

I hope this this helps to some extent:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="raml-http-request-connectorFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="heloo" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply">
            <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="input" doc:name="VM"/>
            <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="output" doc:name="VM"/>
        </request-reply>
        <logger message="log payload is:::::::::::::::::::::#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="raml-http-request-connectorFlow1">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="input" doc:name="VM"/>
        <set-payload value="#[payload+'  welome']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="output" doc:name="VM"/>
    </flow>
```